# Como puedo hacerle parse a dos json

Tags: php, jquery, json

Necesito hacer parse a dos json lo tengo así pero me da error.
La variable `obj.descripcion` no me da error si envió uno pero cuando envió dos me da un error.

json que devuelve PHP y capturo en respuesta

```
{"descripcion_necesidad":"plplpplpl","id_necesidad":"15"} 
{"descripcion_necesidad":"Necesidad por drogas","id_necesidad":"19"}
```

javascript

```
var obj = JSON.parse(respuesta);
console.log(obj.descripcion_necesidad);
```

PHP aquí devuelvo el valor

```
public static function buscarFocoController($datos){

     $respuesta = ideasModels::buscarFocoModels($datos,$_SESSION["id"]);

     $longitud = count($respuesta);

     for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++)
     {
       echo json_encode($enviarDatos = array(
         "descripcion_necesidad"=>$respuesta[$i]["descripcion_necesidad"],
         "id_necesidad"=>$respuesta[$i]["id_necesidad"],
       ));
     }
}
```

Comment: El formato de la respuesta del json está mal. Cómo llegó así?

Comment: ` echo json_encode($enviarDatos = array("descripcion_necesidad"=>$respuesta[$i]["descripcion_necesidad"],
                          "id_necesidad"=>$respuesta[$i]["id_necesidad"],

                      ));`

Comment: cada json debería estar separado por una coma y yo veo que no lo estan, es decir despues de 15 termina un json sería ahí una coma y luego el nuevo json

Comment: es que así como esta los esta leyendo como uno solo

Comment: ese json se genera de esa manera con la funcion json_encode

Comment: @AlbertoJulioArceEscolar por favor agrega el bloque de codigo completo de php donde generas el json y lo envías de vuelta al front

Comment: ¿No tienes ya el array aquí: `$respuesta`?  ¿Por qué usas luego un bucle `for`, porque te interesan sólo algunos elementos del array original? Si ese fuera el caso deberías construir una consulta que te traiga exactamente los datos que quieres, para así no estar trayendo datos para luego desecharlos, lo cual supondría una sobre-carga del servidor. Lo cierto es que, sea como sea, **no necesitas el `for`** y puedes enviar tu objeto haciendo solamente esto: **`echo json_encode($respuesta); //fin del código, no hace falta abrir un bucle for aquí`**

Comment: si no uso el for solo me envia la posicion 0 de la tabla en la base de datos uso un for para recorrer toda la tabla traer todos los campos y convertirlos en json. puede ser 1,2,3 o cualquiera. los json llega el problema es que a la hora de hacer el parse si vienen mas de dos me da un error

Comment: Es muy extraño. Se supone que ya `$respuesta` es un array con todos los datos dentro, si tú haces `echo json_encode($respuesta);` **fuera del `for`**, te creará un JSON válido con todos los datos que hay dentro de `$respuesta`. Si funciona mal significa que hay un error en la lógica del programa, no es normal tener que leer un array para construir otro array con los mismos datos o parte de ellos, no al menos para este tipo de casos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema está en como generás la respuesta json desde PHP.

```
public static function buscarFocoController($datos){

    $respuesta = ideasModels::buscarFocoModels($datos,$_SESSION["id"]);

    $longitud = count($respuesta);

    $json = array();

    for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++)
    {
       // agrego todo a un array
       $json[] = array(
          "descripcion_necesidad"=>$respuesta[$i]["descripcion_necesidad"],
          "id_necesidad"=>$respuesta[$i]["id_necesidad"],
       );

    }
    // una vez que tengo todo el for recorrido y el array armado
    // muestro el json
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Entonces después en javascript:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(respuesta);
// acá vas a tener un array de todos los elementos y dentro el
// objeto con "descripcion_necesidad" y "id_necesidad"
console.log(obj[0].descripcion_necesidad);
```

Comment: asi me funciona, mi pregunta seria ahora como recorro en esta parte `console.log(obj[0].descripcion_necesidad);`

Comment: Podés hacer un `for`, por ejemplo: `for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { console.log(obj[i].descripcion_necesidad); }`.

Comment: Problema resuelto